# Fixed ruby/mysql connection with new libmysql.dll, and broke Apache in the process

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, ruby

Ok so bit of background - all my development has been on a local Windows 7 machine. I had Apache with PHP/MySQL running with no issues.

Been using ruby (1.9.3 and latest rails release 3.2.9) with built in webrick server, but had a devil of a time connecting to mysql. Did some research, updated my libmysql.dll file in c:/ruby/bin and it worked! Very happy... except now Apache stopped working.

In my attempt to resolve the issue I found an older copy of libmysql.dll, renamed the new file, copied the old file back to c:ruby/bin and apache works, ruby does not. So I can take this ass backwards approach but obviously this seems pretty stupid.

I was surprised that Apache was using the dll file in ruby/bin folder. I presume this is related to path variables perhaps? I guess I was hoping someone could direct me as to how I can use one dll file for apache and another for ruby.

Or if you have some other smarter approach - I've smart enough to follow directions to install apache from scratch and enable php on windows as well as ubuntu, but I'm not much of a sys admin, just a semi competent web developer.

Comment: I figured it out - I'm almost embarrassed how easy it was. I copied the apache fixed/ruby broken libmysql.dll file and copied it to Apache/bin, then restored the ruby fixed/apache broken dll file in ruby bin. Problem solved. But I have to wait 6 hours before I can say this issue has been solved. Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I'm almost embarrassed how easy it was. I copied the apache fixed/ruby broken libmysql.dll file and copied it to Apache/bin, then restored the ruby fixed/apache broken dll file in ruby bin. Problem solved.